# await message sending may times over issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Hi I'm encountering an issue where my bot is sending the message `await ctx.send(f":white_check_mark: Member(s) {member_names} kicked from voice channel.")` many times over. This seems to be happening at `await member.move_to(channel = None, reason=None)` say if there is 4 members kicked from the voice channel it will send 4 messages.

Is there a way I can stop this from happening.

Here is my code:

```
 async def voicekick(self, ctx, *members: discord.Member):
    """Kicks a member from voice and restricts them from joining all voice channels.

    - member: The member to kick
    """
    vcr = get(ctx.guild.roles, name="VC Restricted")
    for member in members:
        member_names = ', '.join([x.name for x in members])
        if member.voice is None:
            await ctx.send(f"Member(s) {member_names} not in a voice channel.")
        else:
            await member.move_to(channel = None, reason=None)
            await member.add_roles(vcr)
        await ctx.send(f":white_check_mark: Member(s) {member_names} kicked from voice channel.")
```

Comment: The `send` is inside the `for` loop, it sounds like you want to put it after the `for` loop instead.

Comment: After doing this I get `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'member_names' referenced before assignment` also is there a way I can add `member.voice.channel.name` before `await member.move_to(channel = None, reason=None)` without it looping through the if statement?

Comment: What do you want to add the channel name to?

Comment: I'm looking to add the channel name to the line: `ctx.send(f":white_check_mark: Member(s) {kicked_names} kicked from voice channel.")` which would be `await ctx.send(f":white_check_mark: Member(s) {kicked_names} kicked from {member.voice.channel.name}.")` however channel already = None on the line `await member.move_to(channel = None, reason=None)` so this would mean I would need to move it before this. I tried a `msg =` before that line but that sends a `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'msg' referenced before assignment`

Comment: Do you want to send one message per person, or one message with all the people? What if they were kicked from different channels?

Comment: One message with all people. But you have a good point about whether they'd be in different channels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you kick a member, add their name to a list, then you can display those names after you have kicked all the members:

```
async def voicekick(self, ctx, *members: discord.Member):
    """Kicks a member from voice and restricts them from joining all voice channels.

    - member: The member to kick
    """
    vcr = get(ctx.guild.roles, name="VC Restricted")
    kicked_names = []
    for member in members:
        if member.voice is None:
            await ctx.send(f"Member(s) {member_names} not in a voice channel.")
        else:
            await member.move_to(channel = None, reason=None)
            await member.add_roles(vcr)
            kicked_names.append(member.name)
    kicked_names = ", ".join(kicked_names)
    await ctx.send(f":white_check_mark: Member(s) {kicked_names} kicked from voice channel.")
```